# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') at for loop in parseParsedMessage function

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling

```
function parseMessage(message) {
    let retMessage = '';
    const startIndex = message.indexOf("### Rule ID:");
    const endIndex = message.indexOf("]");
    
    if(startIndex !== -1 && endIndex !== -1 && startIndex < endIndex){
        return message.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
    else{
        return retMessage;
    }
}
function parseParsedMessage(inputString){
    let messagePart = inputString.split('--');
    finalMessagePart = messagePart[1];
    finalElements = [];
    let z = 1;
    for(let i = finalMessagePart.length+1; i > finalMessagePart.length; i--){
        let elements = finalMessagePart.trim().split('-');
        finalElements.push(elements);
    }
    return finalElements;
}
let message = "sbkjeheglhlasd";
let result = parseMessage(message);
let parsedResult = parseParsedMessage(result);

if(parsedResult.length === 0) {
    console.log("Rule ID does not follow the format");
}
else{
    console.log(parsedResult[0][0]);
    console.log(parsedResult[0][1]);
    console.log(parsedResult[0][2]);
    console.log(parsedResult[0][3]);
    console.log(parsedResult[0][4]);
    console.log(parsedResult[0][5]);
    console.log(parsedResult[0][6].replace(']',''));  
}
```

I am trying to handle an exception when rule Id does not follow a specific formation which is like
message:

```
i have a fox with rule id ### tm_violation tm_location tm_market"
```

but I am getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

How do I handle this?

Comment: `result` is an empty string, but you try to split it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseParsedMessage()` should check that `split()` returns at least two parts.

```
function parseParsedMessage(inputString){
    let messagePart = inputString.split('--');
    if (messageParse.length < 2) {
        return [];
    }
    finalMessagePart = messagePart[1];
    finalElements = [];
    let z = 1;
    for(let i = finalMessagePart.length+1; i > finalMessagePart.length; i--){
        let elements = finalMessagePart.trim().split('-');
        finalElements.push(elements);
    }
    return finalElements;
}
```

Comment: My problem is my invalid rule id also starts in the same way, however doesn't follow the format all the way.
eg of invalid rule id ### Rule ID: [asdfghjklT]

Comment: Then add more format checking to `parseMessage`

Comment: can you provide some inputs? I already debugged using log statements

Comment: I moved the validation into `parseParsedMessage()`.